# CRM: What is the difference between update Plugin and Update in XrmServiceToolkit

Tags: dynamics-crm

Is there any difference between updating an entity using a Plugin vs Updating an entity using XrmServiceToolkit?

var entityA= new XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.BusinessEntity("entA", id);

entityA.attributes["attrA"] = { value: attrValue1, type: "OptionSetValue" };

entityA.attributes["attrB"] = { value: attrValue2, type: "Money" };

XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Update(entityA);

I know plugin can be used to connect to external databases but for a very basic update, is there any difference?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Operations in plugins are seemless integrated with the business logic of your CRM platform. Plugins are invoked in any scenario, regardless if they are triggered by a webpage (Javascript calls, e.g. using XrmServiceToolkit), workflow, external systems, integration tools or even other plugins.

An update done on your web page by Javascript only works on that form. If you only need it there, it's fine. If you need to cover other scenarios as well, you may have to look for another solution.

Comment: Henk: your second 'An update done on ...' could be used in some scenarios i guess, like for ex: An Admin Only access form which can have more fields and when data is changed by an admin, then only perform the business logic but I think this is possible with Plugins too by checking the User's role.

Comment: When it comes to doing security checks, a plugin is definitely a better choice. Client scripts are never fully secure, but the server-side checks a plugin can do are.